# Char Function, number to letter grades

Tags: function

I am relatively new to c++ programming and I am struggling with my code. The objective of this code is to take scores input by the user and calculate the mean, the standard deviation and converting it to a letter grade using the calculations under char gradeFunction. When i try to debug this program using visual studios 2013, i am having a couple problems with the the gradefunction. Again i am new to programming so troubleshooting errors is very hard for me and I would appreciate any help or advice! The program looks like this so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void printArray(int Array[], int count);
double average(double scoreTotal, int count);
double stddev(int Array[], int count, double mean);
char gradeFunction(int scores, double stddev, double mean);


int main()
{
    int scores[8];
    int count;
    double scoreTotal = 0;
    int standarddev[8];
    double mean;


    cout << "Enter scores seperated by blanks:" " ";

    for (count = 0; count <= 7; count++)
    {
        cin >> scores[count];
        scoreTotal += scores[count];
        mean = scoreTotal / 8;
    }




    cout << endl;
    cout << "Grade Scores by Student" << endl;
    cout << "Score" "\t" "Grade" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------" << endl;

    printArray(scores, 8);
    cout << gradeFunction(scores, stddev, mean);


    cout << endl;
    cout << "The mean is" " "<< fixed << setprecision(1) << average(scoreTotal, count) << endl;
    cout << "The standard deviation is" " " << stddev(scores, count, mean) <<  endl;
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


void printArray(int Array[], int count)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < count; x++)
    {
        cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << Array[x] << endl;
    }
}

char gradeFunction(int scores, double stddev, double mean)
{
    char F, D, C, B, A;

    if (scores <= (mean - (1.5 * stddev)))
        return 'F';
    else if (scores <= (mean - (.5 * stddev)))
        return 'D';
    else if (scores <= (mean + (.5 * stddev)))
        return 'C';
    else if (scores <= (mean + (1.5 * stddev)))
        return 'B';
    else return 'A';

}


double average(double scoreTotal, int count)
{
    return scoreTotal / count;
}

double stddev(int Array[], int count , double mean)
{
    double stddev;
    double sum2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        sum2 += pow((Array[i] - mean), 2);
    }
    stddev = sqrt(sum2 / (count - 1));
    return stddev;
}
```

**The error messages this leaves me with are...**

```
3   IntelliSense: argument of type "double (*)(int *Array, int count, double mean)" is incompatible with parameter of type "double"
```

Error   1   error C2664: 'char gradeFunction(int [],double,double)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'double (__cdecl *)(int [],int,double)' to 'double'

Comment: You have not defined `stddev` variable before the line `cout << gradeFunction(scores, stddev, mean);`

Comment: Thank you prerak! do you have a suggestion on how I could define it i don't really understand.

Comment: Add `double stddev1 = stddev(scores, count, mean);` after `printArray(scores, 8);` and pass this `stddev1` in `gradeFunction()` instead of `stddev`.